# SqlDataReader.GetSchemaTable() incompatible between .NET Framework 4.7.2 AND .NET6?

Tags: .net

Consider the test below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
   using (var c = new SqlConnection(TestObjectHelper.MSSQLConnectionString))
   {
      c.Open();

      var cmd = c.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE #blabla ( [ts] [timestamp] )";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      cmd = c.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM #blabla";

      using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
         var schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
         var isReadOnly = (bool)schemaTable.Rows[0]["IsReadOnly"];

         Assert.Fail($"env: {Environment.Version}, isReadOnly value: {isReadOnly}");
      }
   }
}
```

The failure message under .NET Framework 4.7.2:

```
env: 4.0.30319.42000, isReadOnly value: True
```

but under .NET6:

```
env: 6.0.20, isReadOnly value: False
```

Both executions were against the same SQL server (version: 2017) instance.

I found no relevant explanations. Did I missed something or should it be reported as a bug?

**UPDATE**
The results do not change if I add `behavior: CommandBehavior.KeyInfo` parameter to the `ExecuteReader` call as *@Charlieface* advised in his comment.

**UPDATE2**
Adding `behavior: CommandBehavior.KeyInfo` even results in duplication of some rows in `schemaTable` based on `ColumnName`: at first glance these column descriptor rows appear to differ in their `IsHidden` values only.

Comment: Quote from the docs *"To make sure that metadata columns return the correct information, you must call ExecuteReader with the behavior parameter set to KeyInfo. Otherwise, some of the columns in the schema table may return default, null, or incorrect data."* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getschematable?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

Comment: Very good point, thanks! Suddently I got the same results with `KeyInfo` behavior.